# Summarized view/categorized display...possibly pivot?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

The best way to ask this question is if I give you an example of what I have and what I'm trying to get.
I have a table that displays all the managers, all the supervisors under these managers and all the employees under these supervisors. What I'm trying to get is to present the same information but formated in a way where managers and supervisors are not repeated like they are in my current table. 
So, this is the original table:

```js
Manager  Supervisor Employee Employee's Title Employee Name
John Smith Pete Adams 15352  Analyst   Tiffany Johnson
John Smith Pete Adams 43543  Developer  David Jackson
John Smith Pete Adams 54553  Programmer  Mike Dudley
John Smith Patricia Salomon36656  Analyst   Josh Adkins
John Smith Patricia Salomon5676  Developer  Beth Davidoff
John Smith Patricia Salomon78568  Programmer  Rick Tyler
Jody Melito Ana Carlisle 6783  Architect  Justin Acevedo
Jody Melito Ana Carlisle 1747  Designer  Joey Smith
```

and this is what I'd like to get:

```js
Manager  Supervisor     Employee   Employee's Title   Employee Name Total
John Smith Pete Adams     15352    Analyst     Tiffany Johnson 3
                43543    Developer        David Jackson 
                54553    Programmer    Mike Dudley 
      Patricia Salomon36656    Analyst        Josh Adkins     3
                5676    Developer        Beth Davidoff 
                78568    Programmer    Rick Tyler 
Jody Melito Ana Carlisle    6783    Architect        Justin Acevedo 2
                1747    Designer        Joey Smith
```

So, basically, what I'm trying to do here is avoid repeating the names of the managers and/or supervisors if they are repeating.
I've done this in Excel but using PIVOT but I'm not sure I can do the same thing in SQL Server as TSQL's PIVOT requires that I aggregate data and I'm not doing that here. Also, I feel there should be a more simple way to do this.
Does anyone have an idea?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
with dat as (
  select * 
       , rn1 = row_number() over (partition by manager order by employee)
       , cnt1 = count(*) over (partition by manager)
       , rn2 = row_number() over (partition by manager, Supervisor order by employee)
       , cnt2 = count(*) over (partition by manager, Supervisor)
  from ( 
    values ('John Smith','Pete Adams','15352')
         , ('John Smith','Pete Adams','15353')
         , ('John Smith','Patricia Salomon','36656')
         , ('John Smith','Patricia Salomon','36658')
    ) yt (Manager,Supervisor,Employee)
)
select manager1    = case when rn1 = 1 then manager else null end
     , managerC    = case when rn1 = 1 then cnt1 else null end
     , supervisor1 = case when rn2 = 1 then supervisor else null end      
     , supervisorC = case when rn2 = 1 then cnt2 else null end      
     , *
from dat   
order by manager, rn1, supervisor, rn2, employee
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer A ツ! It looks like I might be on the right track with your query as it properly shows the managers and supervisors however the employees are not correctly displayed. The employees that should be under one supervisor are displayed as if they belong under a different supervisor. I'll try to fix that. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @dk2014 (headbang) can't of course not order by rn1 and rn2, changed it

Comment: @A ツ unfortunately the employees are still all over the place and fall under wrong supervisors

Comment: @A ツ - nevermind, I must have missed one of your edits...when I copied your code again it worked fine. Thanks! Is there a way to put a Total column for each supervisor in the row when supervisor's name is displayed? For example, Pete Admas has 3 employees working under him while Ana Carlisle has 2

Comment: i edited again after creating the fiddle (which i should have done from the start) anyway, with a count this time: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1796/0